# fpdf shows &#39; instead of single quote

Tags: php, pdf, decode, fpdf

When I get content from my database it shows the single quotes as ISO code instead of the '. Ive tried every type of encoding and decoding but nothing seems to have effect.

It displays `&#39;` instead of single quote.

this is the file that gets the data from the database

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
login_check($mysqli);
user_data_check($mysqli);
$data = totaal_factuur_data_1($mysqli, $_GET['ref']);
$kost = totaal_factuur_data_2($mysqli, $_GET['ref']);

include 'factuur.php';
$pdf->Output($data[0] . '.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

And this is the factuur.php file.

```
<?php
define('EURO',chr(128));
$hoog = 0;
$laag = 0;
$totaal = explode('<br>', $kost[0]);
foreach($kost as $key => $value) {
if($key != 0) {
    if ($value[2] == 21) {
        $hoog++;
    }

    if ($value[2] == 6) {
        $laag++;
    }
}
}

if($hoog > 0) {
    if ($laag > 0) {
        $toteen = EURO . punt_naar_komma($totaal[0]) . "\n" . EURO .     punt_naar_komma($totaal[1]). "\n" . EURO . punt_naar_komma($totaal[2]). "\n" . EURO .     punt_naar_komma($totaal[3]);
    $tottwee = "Bedrag:\n6% BTW:\n21% BTW:\nTotaal:";
} else {
    $toteen = EURO . punt_naar_komma($totaal[0]) . "\n" . EURO . punt_naar_komma($totaal[1]) . "\n" . EURO . punt_naar_komma($totaal[2]);
    $tottwee = "Bedrag:\n21% BTW:\nTotaal:";
}
} elseif($laag > 0) {
$toteen = EURO . punt_naar_komma($totaal[0]) . "\n" . EURO . punt_naar_komma($totaal[1]). "\n" . EURO . punt_naar_komma($totaal[2]);
$tottwee = "Bedrag:\n6% BTW:\nTotaal:";
} else {
$toteen = EURO . punt_naar_komma($totaal[0]) . "\n" . EURO . punt_naar_komma($totaal[1]);
$tottwee = "Bedrag:\nTotaal:";
}

require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{

function FancyTable($data)
{
$this->SetFillColor(100,100,100);
$this->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
$this->SetDrawColor(100,100,100);
$this->SetLineWidth(.1);
$this->SetFontSize(11);
$this->SetFont('','B');
$this->Cell(115,7,'Omschijving',1,0,'L',true);
$this->Cell(35,7,'Btw tarief',1,0,'C',true);
$this->Cell(40,7,'Bedrag',1,0,'R',true);
$this->Ln();

$this->SetFillColor(214,214,214);
$this->SetTextColor(0);
$this->SetFont('');
$fill = false;
foreach($data as $key => $row)
{
    $output_data = str_replace("_", " ", $row[4]);
    if($key != 0) {
        $this->Cell(115,6,$output_data,'LR',0,'L',$fill);
        if($row[2] == 6 || $row[2] == 21 || $row[2] == 0) {
            $this->Cell(35,6,$row[2] . '%','LR',0,'C',$fill);
        } else {
            $this->Cell(35,6,$row[2],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
        }
        $this->Cell(40,6,EURO . punt_naar_komma($row[0]),'LR',0,'R',$fill);
        $this->Ln();
        $fill = !$fill;
    }
}
$this->Cell(190 ,0,'','T');
}

function Header()
{
$data = $GLOBALS['data'];

$klant_data = explode('^', $data[3]);
if($data[8] == 0) {
    $titel = 'Factuur';
} else if($data[8] == 1) {
    $titel = 'Creditnota';
} if($data[8] == 2) {
    $titel = 'Offerte';
}

if(strlen($klant_data[5]) < 2) {
    $this->SetFont('Arial','b',24);
    $this->Cell(35, 40, $titel, '', '', 'L');
    $this->Ln(50);
} else {
    $this->Image('/home/deb60170n7/domains/ezboekhouding.nl/data/settings/' . $klant_data[5],10,10,'', 40);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','b',14);
    $this->Ln(25);
    $this->Cell(155, 0, $titel, '', '0', 'R');
    $this->Ln(25);
}

$klant .= $klant_data[0] . "\n";
$klant .= $klant_data[1] . "\n";
$klant .= $klant_data[2] . "\n";
$klant .= $klant_data[3] . ' ' . $klant_data[4];

$klant = utf8_decode($klant);

$adres_data= explode('^', $data[4]);
if($data[1] != '*') {
    $adres .= 'T.a.v. ' . $data[1] . "\n";
}
$adres .= $adres_data[0] . "\n";
$adres .= $adres_data[1] . "\n";
$adres .= $adres_data[2] . " " . $adres_data[3];



$this->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$x = $this->GetX();
$y = $this->GetY();
$this->SetTextColor(100,100,100);
$this->MultiCell(90, '5', $klant , '0', 'L');
$this->SetXY($x + 105, $y);
$this->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$this->MultiCell(90, '5', $adres , '0', 'L');
$this->Ln(15);
$this->Cell(35, 0, 'Factuur datum:', '', '', 'L');
$this->Cell(70, 0, $data[2]);
$this->Cell(30, 0, 'BTW nummer:', '', '', 'R');
$this->Cell(30, 0, $data[6]);
$this->Ln(5);
$this->Cell(35, 0, 'Factuur nummer:', '', '', 'L');
$this->Cell(70, 0, $data[0]);
$this->Cell(30, 0, 'KVK nummer:', '', '', 'R');
$this->Cell(30, 0, $data[7]);
$this->Ln(5);
$this->Cell(0,0,'',1);
$this->Ln(5);
}

function Footer()
{
$data = $GLOBALS['data'];
$this->SetY(-15);
$this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
$adres_data= explode('^', $data[3]);
if($data[8] == 0) {
    $text = 'Wij verzoeken u het bedrag zo snel mogelijk over te maken naar rekeningnummer ' . $data[5] . ' t.n.v. ' . $adres_data[6] . ' o.v.v. het factuur nummer.';
} else if($data[8] == 1) {
    $text = '';
} if($data[8] == 2) {
    $text = '';
}
$this->Cell(0,'', $text, 0, 0, 'C');
$this->Ln();
$this->Cell(0,10,'Pagina '.$this->PageNo(),0,0,'C');
}
}

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->FancyTable($kost);
$pdf->Ln(1);
$pdf->Cell(115);
$x = $pdf->GetX();
$y = $pdf->GetY();
$pdf->MultiCell(35, '5', $tottwee , '', 'R');
$pdf->SetXY($x + 35, $y);
$pdf->MultiCell(40, '5', $toteen , '', 'R');
?>
```

Can somebody tell me the correct way of decoding the this? Ive also tried to set the

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

with all the standard html quotes but then the fpdf class gives an error that some data already had been outputted and it cannot display an pdf file.

I tried to decode it within the Header function. I don't know if this has any effect on the decoding  such as iconv or utf8_decode?. I think the problem is something else because i also tried decoding within the file that gets the data from the database with an for loop.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try either `html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES);` or `htmlspecialchars_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES);`. See if that will outout your value better.

Comment: Can't tell you how to decode a string we can't see. Post some sample content from your database.

Comment: @Rasclatt It worked. I tried html_entity_decode but without the ENT_QUOTES. Thanks a lot! Whats the difference?

Comment: No problem. Usually people forget or don't know that it has that option.